# Generating one more name from azurecaf_name changes previously generated names

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm, azurecaf

I had this code:

```
resource "azurecaf_name" "names" {
  name            = var.appname
  resource_type   = "azurerm_resource_group"
  resource_types  = ["azurerm_mssql_server", "azurerm_mssql_database", "azurerm_app_service_plan"]
  prefixes        = [var.environment]
  suffixes        = [var.resource_group_location_short]
  random_length   = 5
  clean_input     = false
}
```

I then only changed the line

```
resource_types  = ["azurerm_mssql_server", "azurerm_mssql_database", "azurerm_app_service_plan"]
```

to

```
resource_types  = ["azurerm_mssql_server", "azurerm_mssql_database", "azurerm_app_service_plan", "azurerm_storage_account"]
```

(change is at the ed of the line: azurerm_storage_account was added)

After that, when running terraform apply, all resources were re-created as the azurerm_resource_group generated by azurecaf_name was changed. How can I prevent that? My expectation is that adding a new resource type to azurecaf_name does not change previously generated names.

Comment: Couple of possibilities (may be others) 1. Azure API enforces this 2. provider does not distinguish between the delta of the original entries and the new entries, but rather merely acts on it being different versus idempotent

Comment: Do you mean the azurecaf_name respurce was replaced? Ot it was modified but you are using a count meta item in another resource based off resource types attribute?

Comment: According to the documentation, that resource "generates a name using the input parameters". You changed the input parameters. It seems like you are asking how to prevent the name from changing when you change the input parameters, but that defeats the entire purpose of the resource.  It seems to be working as intended to me. If there are other resources in your terraform code that changed unexpectedly because of this, you should include those in your question, and also include the `terraform plan` output in your question so that we can see exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prevent that? My expectation is that adding a new resource type to azurecaf_name does not change previously generated names.

I tried to replicate the same in my environment by adding a `Storage account` as a resource type after creating the resources using the Terraform code. However, it is destroying the existing resource and creating a new one.

[image]

The `CAF` name was successfully created according to the specified resource type.

```
 cafname = "dev-rg-sample123-dmrdd-eastus"
```

When I try to add a storage account to the resource type in the same code, the `CAF` name is automatically changing to include the prefix `ST` based on the `storage account`.

```
Caf name = dev-st-sample123-weffa
```

The storage account resource type code is `ST`. Please refer to the [Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/aztfmod/azurecaf/latest/docs/resources/azurecaf_name) for information about the naming convention.

> Note: If you change or add resource types in the same code, the existing `CAF` will be destroyed by default, and a new `CAF` will be created with a different name based on the resource type.
> [image]

The `CAF` name is consistently changing according to the resource type

The `CAF` name is being changed to a different name after adding a Storage Account.

```
Caf name = dev-st-sample123-weffa
```

Refer this [Doc](https://github.com/aztfmod/terraform-azurerm-caf-naming#known-issues) more about resource type.